# how to timestamp a binary (.jar) after signing

Tags: linux, java, timestamp, code-signing

I have a jar which I want to sign and timestamp with timestamping server(tsa). I am using the following command to codesign and timestamp the binary.

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore macert.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass mypass -keypass mypass myjar.jar "myaliase" -tsa http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp
```

The binary is signed but not timestamped by tsa. following is the command to check if the binary is timestamped or not:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs myjar.jar | grep "entry was signed on"
```

Could someone tell me how can I further debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Using following command it can be signed and timestamp:

```
#jarsigner -verbose -tsa http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp -keystore macert.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass mypass -keypass mypass myjar.jar "myaliase"
```

If the binary is not timestamped then one thing you can check is:
We need to make sure that timestamp server is reachable, that you can do as following

```
    #telnet sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com 443

GET /sha256/timestamp
```

If it is available that means your timestamp server is okay.